# just started working in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I know the languages separately but not when it comes to combining them and I'm not sure how to do this ... so what i'm trying to do is easy on the page to appear a button that will take me to the top but unfortunately there is nothing on the page during the scroll ... so any ideas or what should i do[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woe5W.png)

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        echo '<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.onscroll = function() {
            scrollFunction()
        };';
        echo 'function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 40) {
                document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
            }
        }';
        echo 'function topFunction() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        }';
        echo '</script>';
        require "index-content.html";

    }
    else {
        echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP you can enter HTML directly "as is".  You typically will use `echo` when you need PHP to interpret something server side.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code that will work.  I added two divs with some color to show your code working.

```php
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
?>
<!-- remove this line -->
<div style="height:100%; background-color: green;"></div>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<!-- remove this line -->
<div style="height:100%; background-color: red;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onscroll = function() {
        scrollFunction()
    };
    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 40) {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
        }
    };
    function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    };
</script>

<?php
// uncomment this line
// require "index-content.html";
} else {
?>
<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>
<?php
}
?>
```